# Pure virtual function with implementation fails in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I have some pure virtual function in a class, that is defined in header file, like this:

```
virtual string GetStdString() = 0
{
    // some code
}
```

On windows it works fine, but compiling with XCode I have an error

> "Expected ';' at end of declaration list"

that points to the end of line with function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever compiler you're using on Windows is wrong on this. That code should not compile. You *can* provide a body for a pure virtual function, but you cannot do so *in the same declaration* (pretty much only because the standard says so). Change your code like this:

```
class TheClass
{
  virtual string GetStdString() = 0;
};

inline string TheClass::GetStdString()
{
  // some code
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Using your hint I formulated a correct request and found a couple of links. For example http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/pure-virtual-function/

Comment: The standard seems quit arbitrary here to me but I like your explanation "... because the standard says so". :-)